# OSM Updating issue with vectores

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, quickmapservices

I have a project file that contains OSM from QuickMapService, and I always insert vectors on this OSM map, the issue here is when the OSM got updated the streets shift, and my vectors ( Lines, Points ... etc ) are still on the old update of OSM which makes my lines, points, ... etc intersect with each other like images below, and I have only one solution on my mind which is making an offline version of OSM but the issue here that I can't do this because when I use the OSM on Qfield I'll face problem figuring out the streets

Note: You can see the green line before the update and how it shifted after the update

[image]
[image]